# What does “Reference implementation” mean?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn about CachedRowSet in Java, and I am reading some tutorials about it.
I have come across reference implementation terminology very often.

For example

> Alternatively, you can use the constructor from the CachedRowSet
>   implementation of your JDBC driver. **However, implementations of the
>   RowSet interface will differ from the reference implementation**.
>   These implementations will have different names and constructors. For
>   example, the Oracle JDBC driver's implementation of the CachedRowSet
>   interface is named oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.

Could anyone please be kind and explain this?

Note, I have found some definitions on the web that are too vague for me to understand.

Comment: A reference implementation is basically an example implementation written by the creators of the API that showcases how they intended it to be used.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means the implementation of the specification that should demonstrate the concepts. Mostly it is implemented by the same guys/company that designed the specification.

You may think of specification as a standard that is needed to allow other possible implementation to be compatible with the rest of the world. And the reference implementation of a proof-of-concept kind piece of software that should show how to do that and encourage others to create their own implementations.

In the JDBC context it means, that there are some interfaces (`CachedRowSet`) prescribing some methods and there is a reference implementation to these interfaces done in Sun/Oracle.

Comment: "We provide thesedocs that specify a protocol, but if the documents do not cover all the cases, when in doubt do as X does"

Comment: Just that the RI issue is just an acknowledgement that the specification *per se* may be incomplete, ambiguous or even contradictory, so that relating to an specific implementation to decide on those grey areas is needed.

Comment: Does it mean the same here also? "The final part of the guide will be giving clues for next steps for the curious developer, who would like to give the Java reference implementation a try." Reference: https://serefarikan.com/2012/11/08/openehr-for-practical-people-cleaned-up/

Answer (score 7):

`JSR (Java Specification Request)` - theory

`RI (Reference Implementation)` - concrete, working code proving that JSR can work. Basically, a **sample** implementation.

You can create your own implementation of any [JSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process#List_of_JSRs) and use RI as an example if you're not sure about something.