# How does spring MVC do form validation (using hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am following a tutorial, that showed us how to build using `Spring MVC` framework a simple form that can be validated.

We created a function annotated using `RequestMapping` then added `@Valid` as annotation to the first argument of this function along side `@ModelAttribute` annotation. Let's call the first argument type `ClassA`.

Now in `ClassA` we annotated some of its properties with `hibernate` validation annotations (e.g. `@NotNull`, `@Pattern`, etc...)

What I am trying to understand is how is this all working?

I checked the code for `@interface NotNull` for example and it really does nothing.

I am assuming that the `spring MVC` framework, uses reflection to detect that the first argument of the `RequestMapping` function is annotated using `Valid`, then when the form is submitted is calls `SOMETHING` to validate `ClassA` properties.

Where is this `SOMETHING`? Is it in hibernate? Code please... How did `Spring` figure out to call `hibernate` code, we just added the `hibernate` `jars` to the project but at no point we told `Spring` to use them.

Also, what is the specification that binds `Spring MVC` to hibernate?

Can someone is simple terms and using high level (and references of code if possible) explain to me how things are working?

I am very new to this and coming from C++ where things are done very differently. I am trying to understand the mechanisms behind the workings of `Spring`.

Comment: Here is the link that explains how the validation works http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is Spring's support to [JSR-303 Bean Validation API](http://beanvalidation.org/). Those annotations such as `@NotNull`, `@Pattern` are all part of this JSR. Since this is just a JSR (basically, JSR is just a set of interfaces), it needs a concrete implementation in order to actually work (called the provider). Here is where hibernate comes in the picture. Hibernate owns an implementation of JSR-303, called the [`hibernate-validator`](http://hibernate.org/validator/). This API has nothing to do with the core ORM functionalities of Hibernate. In fact, this API is the [reference implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824843/what-does-reference-implementation-means) of JSR-303, that is why in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) you will see that it is used as the default provider.

So as the user of Spring framework, all you need to know is Spring needs to find an implementation of JSR-303 in the classpath so that you can start using those annotation from `javax.validation.*` package.